# Orderby clause not working with drop down list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am populating a drop down list using Linq and the orderby clause doesn't seem to work.

```
 public List<Hello> getManagers()
         {
             var que = (from man in db.Table1
                        where man.Role == "Manager"
                        orderby man.Name
                        select new Hello
                        {
                           Managers = man.Name
                        }).Distinct().ToList();
             return que;
         }
```

Controller Class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            rp = new RequestProcess();
            ViewBag.ID = fillSelectedList("", "ID", rp);
            ViewBag.Managers = fillSelectedList("", "Managers", rp);
            return View(""); //View 1
        }
public static List<SelectListItem> fillSelectedList(string selValue, string type,  RequestProcess rp )
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem obj = new SelectListItem();
            if (type == "Managers") {
                 var tempList= rp.getManagers(); 
                tempList.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    obj = new SelectListItem();
                    obj.Text = x.Managers;
                    obj.Value = x.Managers;
                    obj.Selected = x.Managers == selValue ? true : false;
                    list.Add(obj);
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
```

I am still receiving an un-ordered list. Any fixes?

Comment: Where are you calling `getManagers()`? What is `fillSelectedList()?`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated the edits, forgot about that part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not ordered, because method `Distinct` does not return ordered results. What you need to do instead is to first call `Disctinct`, and only then `OrderBy`:

```
var que = (from man in db.Table1
    where man.Role == "Manager"
    select new Hello
    {
        Managers = man.Name
    }).Distinct()               // <- First distinct ...
    .OrderBy(x => x.Managers)   // <- ... then order by
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to sort the result after `Distinct()`.

Also note that you are mixing *Lambda expression* and *LINQ to Entities* Queries... you may want to consider choosing one of them for consistency (though there is no syntax error if you mix them). This is the same query using lambda expression:

```
 var que = _context.Table1
           .Where(m => m.Role == "Manager")
           .Select(h => new Hello { Managers = h.Name })
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(o => o.Managers)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Duly noted! Thank you :)